# CSS rule not applied when CSS selector not specific enough

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with the class `menucontainer` where I apply the following style. I want to apply a style to all first children of that parent container but the style is not being applied without adding html body `menucontainer` > * but it applies the style to `.menucontainer` without adding html body `menucontainer`. Can someone explain this behavior or what I'm doing wrong here

```
.menucontainer
    {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

/* this works */
    html body .menucontainer > * {
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
```

```
.menucontainer > * {
        margin-right: 40px;
}
```

This doesn't but this `.menucontainer` does apply the style to `.menucontainer`

Answer (score 0):

From `www.w3schools.com`:

> If there are two or more CSS rules that point to the same element, the
> selector with the highest specificity value will "win", and its style
> declaration will be applied to that HTML element.
>
> Think of specificity as a score/rank that determines which style
> declaration is ultimately applied to an element.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: I only have the selector ```.menucontainer``` and ```.menucontainer > *```  in my whole CSS. Is ```.menucontainer``` treated in the same way as  ```.menucontainer > *```?

Comment: Are you using any CSS framework e.g. Bootstrap or any other CSS file? I created a JSFiddle with your code and the style is applied correctly without adding `html body`: https://jsfiddle.net/0nvjmw2g/

Comment: You can use browser inspect element tool and check which CSS rules are applied to each element. https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-inspect